# Sharing Model Objects from Java project with Android

Tags: java, android, jackson, gson, dalvik

What would be the best way to share Model objects from regular java project with Android? The issue I am having is that these Domain Model have annotations that is not supported in Android. For example javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement, XmlAttribute etc. On the server side, we have Jackson for serialization and deserialization. So using the same on Android causes the app to crash (API level 16, with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement, work on 18+ though) I would prefer not to duplicate these classes in Android. Any guys use pojo with such annotation in Android?

Example Class:

```
public class StoreInfo {
   @JsonDeserialize(using = OpearingHoursDeserializer.class)
   OpearingHours operatingHours
...
   @XmlElement(name = "hoursOfOperation")   // Annotation not present in Android
   public OperatingHours getOperatingHours() {
       return this.operatingHours;
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked, but you could download the missing library and add it to your project yourself. This could easily be done with Maven if you're using Android Studio.

Comment: It's the javax annotations which is not supported by Android.  I am using Jackson library and it works on newer version.  Only crashes in older api level.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jackson on the android side too? If it can serialize your data it should be able to deserialize it on android too.
Some code examples would be nice.

Comment: I am using Jackson on android side. I even tried Gson. Question is regarding reusing these model objects that have annotations not supported by android.

Comment: Well some code might help and a better description of your problem. What are the models used for on the serverside? Just for sending the data or are they annotated with JPA annotations too? The next question is, are you in charge of the server code? do you have to use xml or can you switch to json for example.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. There are no JPA annotations. They have xml and jackson annotations, used in a Spring MVC app to generate response body as JSON and XML. In the app side we are only doing JSON. Trying to use the same model so I do not have to duplicate the model objects in app. Otherwise it would be exact copy of the objects without annotations.

Comment: What version on Jackson do you use? Did you include the jackson-module-jaxb-annotations module?

Comment: I did not include jaxb annotation module. The issue I am having is with javax bind annotation which is part of Java, and is not present in Android.

Comment: Well the point as I see it is that these annotations do not exist and this module would provide them. You can write a dummy yourself too if you want.